# Internet Explorer 8 - Session Shared among Explorer Window

Tags: internet-explorer-8

**IE 8** sharing session among different Explorer Window for same domain.

Like if you are a logined at hotmail.com in IE 8, and you have open another explorer window for hotmail.com, you will automatically logined.

This was not in **IE 7**, In IE 7 session has shared in the same explorer tab rather different Explorer Window.

Can anyone have a idea about this, Whether it is bug or something else in **IE 8**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use

**File -> New Session**

Well, it is not a bug. Browsers usually share data via cookies. IE8 have this 'new session' feature to let you use multiple email accounts (and similar services) with multiple browsers.

Answer (score 5):

Modify IE8 Shortcut to Permanently Launch New IE Browser Window in New Session

Right click on the IE8 shortcut (all IE8 shortcuts or icons on desktop, Start Menu, Quick Launch bar or Taskbar that you want it to run as a new instance session have to be changed), and choose Properties from the right click context menu. Then, append -nomerge to the end of the of the program path in “Target” text box at “Shortcut” tab. For example,

```
“C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe” -nomerge
```

link
http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/07/22/run-separate-isolated-ie8-window-frame-session-with-nomerge-switch-for-multiple-logins/

Answer (score 1):

Create a new shortcut to ieplore.exe, add the -nomerge switch. This will always start a new session.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using "Run" and just type "iexplore.exe -nomerge"

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't that clear.

Are saying in IE8 when you open a new window that window shares the same session as the previous window hence any login made in one is shared by the other?

If so then that would be normal behaviour and not any different to the way IE7 handled it.

OTH are you saying that when you open a new window in IE8 it doesn't continue to share the same session as the previous window?  If you mean using the New Window action from the Page menu then that would appear to be a bug to me but it doesn't happen on my copy of IE8.

If by new window you mean starting a new instance of IE from quick links or Start menu then it would be correct for that to start a new session and not share session cookies with the other session you have running.

I suspect this last is the real situation, previously the standard IE link added to Start Menu or Desktop would simply open a new window using one of any existing IE sessions currently running, IE8 doesn't do that it will invoke a new session from this link.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent new windows from sharing session cookies by File -> New Session, however you cannot prevent new tabs from sharing data by default.

Answer (score -1):

Any new window that you open (using iexplore.exe and not openning from inside another window) shares the same session as any previous.

1. Open a window and log in into your bank account.
2. Open another window (blank window).
3. Close the bank account window by clicking on the X.
4. Wait 5 minutes (just to emphasize the problem).
5. open another window and type the bank account address.

Result => You are logged into the bank account.

Don't tell me that this is not a bug. This is a huge one! (maybe a design bug)

Most users do not expect this behavior and complain that there is a "problem with our site" because they have another window open on some radiostation which makes sure the session of another site is persisted, I then have to explain to them that Microsoft/Google decided that that's the "right" way. The default should be -nomerge and not the other way around.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a bug. Right or wrong it is behaving as intended. When you open the second window it is automatically tied to the existing session. The only way to kill the session or ensure a new active session is to use File->New Session or close every browser. Users have multiple application windows open that authenticate to Active Directory. If one 'times out' and you have to re-sign in it can play havok as the other windows are still based on the initial sign-in session. Now two sign-ins are pretending to be the active session and don't play nice with each other.

Comment: @Kevin - I tried fitting your answer into a comment here, but I may have butchered your meaning. You might want to edit it as you see fit.

Comment: so how come most users complain about this behavior ? they expect a new session when clicking on the IE icon